# How do I perform a function repeatedly on a list of values?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file with VBA code already imbedded.  This template file essentially creates a new file based on a primary key identifier.  I have a master data file that the template uses to look up the particular values to fill in and then the template fills in the data based on the primary key.  The VBA code then copies and pastes these values into a new worksheet, that then looks like the template with all of the fields filled in using the data from the master file.

I currently have to input each primary key and re-run the VBA code to create a new file for each primary key.

I have the list of primary keys and I would like to bookend the existing code with code that will repeat the functions for each primary key in the list without having to manually enter each one.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim TheFileName As String
    Dim TheResponse As Integer
    Dim Modelworkbook As String

    TheFileName = Range("C_filename").Value

    '=======================================
    ' Copy data into new worksheet
    '=======================================

    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A21:I91").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    '=======================================
    ' Setup new print area and page setup
    '=======================================

    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$21:$I$91"
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    End With
    Range("B48").Select

    '=======================================
    ' Prepare to save new worksheet export
    '=======================================

    '===============================
    ' CHECK THAT WANT TO EXPORT
    '===============================

    TheResponse = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to export the results to " + TheFileName + "? ", vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "Do you want to continue")

    If TheResponse = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "Export Terminated"
        Application.Goto Reference:="i_name"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '=======================================
    ' Verify that file is not already there
    '=======================================

    If Dir(TheFileName) <> "" Then

        TheResponse = MsgBox(TheFileName + " Already Exists? OVERWRITE? ", vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "Do you want to continue")

        If TheResponse = vbNo Then
            MsgBox "Export Terminated"
            Application.Goto Reference:="i_name"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    '=======================================
    ' Save the file
    '=======================================

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=TheFileName, _
        FileFormat:=51, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    '==============================================
    ' Copy certain formulas from template to export
    '==============================================

    Modelworkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Windows( _
        "1-Loan Status Update Template.xlsm" _
        ).Activate
    Range("B53").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="ValuationAnalysis"
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(Modelworkbook).Activate
    Range("B53").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows( _
        "1-Loan Status Update Template.xlsm" _
        ).Activate
    Range("f89").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="preppedby"
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(Modelworkbook).Activate
    Range("f89").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows( _
        "1-Loan Status Update Template.xlsm" _
        ).Activate
    Range("h37").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="aigparticipation"
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(Modelworkbook).Activate
    Range("h37").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows( _
        "1-Loan Status Update Template.xlsm" _
        ).Activate
    Range("m4").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="concluded"
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(Modelworkbook).Activate
    Range("m4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B23").Select
    Windows( _
        "1-Loan Status Update Template.xlsm" _
        ).Activate
    Range("B51").Select
    Windows(Modelworkbook).Activate
    Range("B23").Select
    Windows( _
        "1-Loan Status Update Template.xlsm" _
        ).Activate
    Application.Goto Reference:="OperPerform"
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(Modelworkbook).Activate
    Range("G42").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows( _
        "1-Loan Status Update Template.xlsm" _
        ).Activate
    Application.Goto Reference:="LoanTermsCalcs"
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(Modelworkbook).Activate
    Range("E32").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows( _
        "1-Loan Status Update Template.xlsm" _
        ).Activate
    Application.Goto Reference:="InvestmentMgr"
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(Modelworkbook).Activate
    Range("F3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValidation, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows( _
        "1-Loan Status Update Template.xlsm" _
        ).Activate
    Application.Goto Reference:="PreparedBy"
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(Modelworkbook).Activate
    Range("F4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValidation, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows( _
        "1-Loan Status Update Template.xlsm" _
        ).Activate
    Application.Goto Reference:="Recommend"
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(Modelworkbook).Activate
    Range("C10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValidation, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False





    '=======================================
    ' ReSave the file
    '=======================================

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=TheFileName, _
        FileFormat:=51, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    '=======================================
    ' Close Exported file
    '=======================================

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code? All I think you would need to do is add those keys to an array, and wrap a loop around your current code.

Comment: '=======================================
    ' Copy data into new worksheet
    '=======================================
    
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A21:I91").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Comment: @AlexanderHawkins There are a number of ways to achieve this. It would be useful if you could show how you are currently passing the Primary Key to your macro (eg is it reading the value from a cell or are you passing it as a parameter to the macro). Also, how do you want to specify the list of primary keys - do you want to hard-code this in the macro, or do you want to include it in a worksheet somewhere (which makes it easier to update the list if needed)?

Comment: @AlexanderHawkins post code by editing into your question, not as a comment. And don't forget to format it as code (there's a button in the editor for that)

Comment: thanks for the advice - i input the code above in the original question

Comment: @AlexanderHawkins thanks for editing the code into the Q.  But please pay more attention to code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Use a Range object for a group of cells. Get the value for the cell and then validate it it before you call your routine.

This example assumes you are using a whole column and will stop at the first blank cell, only using Long values:

```
Public Sub RunForColumnB()

    Dim oColumn As Range
    Dim oCell As Range
    Dim sVal As String

    'this looks in column B on Sheet1
    Set oColumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B")

    For Each oCell In oColumn
        sVal = oCell.Value
        If sVal = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf IsNumeric(sVal) Then

            'your code goes here
            Debug.Print CLng(sVal)

        End If
    Next 'oCell

End Sub
```